# CSS intellisense not working after migrating MVC 5 Project to Bower

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, bower

I've just switched a project over to using Bower and I now have blue squigglies under all the CSS classes from bower packages in my views:

[image: Blue squigglies in HTML view]

I'm guessing this is because intellisense isn't finding the CSS files?

I've set Bower up to put all the files it downloads in a folder called lib at the root of my web project, that lib folder isn't included in the project in VS:

[image]

I don't really want to add that folder as it will contain thousands of files and make the proj file huge I imagine (I did try adding it, but VS just went unresponsive).

The Bower CSS files are being loaded into the project using the MVC bundler:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.*",
    "~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.*",
    "~/lib/AdminLTE/dist/css/AdminLTE.*",
    "~/lib/AdminLTE/dist/css/skins/skin-blue-light.*",
    "~/lib/AdminLTE/dist/css/skins/skin-green-light.*",
    "~/Content/site.css"));
```

I'm using ReSharper, but switching it to use VS's Intellisense doesn't make any difference.  [Dave Paquette seems to have identified a similar issue in VS2013](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/02/09/ensuring-intellisense-for-bower-packages-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=ensuring-intellisense-for-bower-packages-in-visual-studio-2013), is this just the expected behaviour with Bower?